# how to vertically align this select element

Tags: html, css

I have a basic css question. I'm trying to add css to my form, the code is below:

```
<div id="content">
<form id="form1" method="post" action="">
  <p>
    <label for="name" class="title">Your name:</label>
    <input name="name" type="text" class="widebox" id="name">
  </p>
  <p>
    Colour: <select name="colour_pref" size "1">
    <option value="1">Pink</option>
    <option value="2">Blue</option>
    <option value="3">White</option></select>
  </p>
  <p class="submit">
    <input type="submit" name="add" value="add_colour" id="add">
  </p>
</form>
</div>
```

and this is the css:

```
#content p {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #efefef;
    margin: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    width: 260px;}
.title {
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
    text-align: right;
    padding-right: 10px;}
.submit {
    text-align: right;}
```

The problem is the select element is not aligned with the name field, I tried to add class="title" to it but it made it even messier. 
Would really appreciate if you could help me align this select element VERTICALLY with the text field. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Something like this DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/kevinPHPkevin/XzHG2/1/

```
.submit input {
    margin-left:110px;
}
```

Comment: This is a bad way of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

Just add `display inline` to your pararaph:

```
p {
    display: inline;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/rp6aR/)

Comment: sorry I forgot to add, I want to vertically align them